# script that able to download zip file from server

Tags: python, urllib2

Can you please help me to make script in python that do the following:

1. download zip file http (I already have a code for this one)
2. download zip file in `file://<server location>`, I have problem with this one. the location of the file is in `file://<server location>file.zip`

can't download the #2 file :(

Code below, #1 is working if using HTTP, but when using `file:////` it's not working. Anybody has idea how to download a zip file from `file:////`?

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('file:////server/file.zip')
print response.info()
html = response.read()
# do something
response.close()  # best practice to close the file
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Code so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

urllib2 does not have handlers for the `file://` protocol; I think it will open local files if there is *no* protocol given (`//server/file.zip`), but I've never used that, and haven't tested it.  If you have a local file name, you can just use `open()` and `read()` rather than urrlib2.

Your code will be simpler if you use `with closing` (from `contextlib`); opened files are already context managers in Python 2.7 and 3.x, so they're even easier to use.